# .pyc not generated while creating module

Tags: python-3.x, command-prompt, python-module

I am trying to create a python module but a .pyc file is not created. I am working in windows. I execute 2 commands in command prompt(which I run as administrator) as following:
c:\Python33\python.exe setup.py sdist
after this statement is executed in the same window I execute
c:\Python33\python.exe setup.py install
I don't know what I am lacking???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python3.x doesn't create .pyc files in the same directory. This is [part of python3's `__pycacahe__` standard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_6vDi7ywuA#t=1175). Instead, your .pyc files are stored in `__pycache__` for the version that you build for.

This was mentioned in [Brett Cannon's talk at Pycon-2013](http://pyvideo.org/video/1730/python-33-trust-me-its-better-than-27)

Comment: Should I copy that file or just carry on with import statement?

Comment: @kartikey_kant: "Keep calm and import on"